# IDE issue or genuine error?

Tags: php, ide

```
public function first(){
        return $this->results()[0];
    }
```

My IDE (PHP Designer 8) flags (in red) the above function return line that gets the first value from the database however when I run it there are no errors thrown and it produces the expected results (see below). If I remove the [0] then the flag disappears.

```
stdClass Object ( 
  [id] => 2
  [username] => jhcorsair 
  [password] => b40ad7a04a1d37828697197d3eeb893a4aac4f6ba1e6cce3bb4bedeb6354e266 
  [salt] => N#ˆ˜ºÕJ(Ò³v^ºË,˜iÚ¢E\~£É±šé7Ô
  [name] => 0
  [joined] => 2014-09-16 06:24:55 
  [group] => 1 
)
```

Is this truly a syntax error or an IDE issue?

Comment: It helps if you add at least a language tag. My IDEs (Visual Studio 2013 and RAD Studio XE7) flag this as totally invalid syntax, because neither of them supports PHP. Please be more specific when tagging your questions. :-)

Comment: Is you function in a class? Because you can use `public` onlyy in classes. However I highly recommend you to use PHPStorm IDE. It's pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an IDE issue. It appears that the IDE does not recognize that results() is returning a list. I've noticed that IDEs will often flag this kind of syntax (when you are offsetting into an anonymous temporary variable). If you want to get rid of the warning, try assigning the result to a local variable.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I think I'll leave it alone for now unless I run into more problems down the road :)